# Deleting a question also deletes the answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, deleted-questions

I sometimes answer questions (complexity theory or something like that) that are not so popular.

Sometimes such questions get deleted after a while. I cannot say if it was the OP or after closed as off-topic or something else, but if the question gets deleted, my answer gets deleted too.

I put some effort into my answers, so I would like to have the chance to access my answer after the question is deleted, maybe only for some time so I can safe the answer to my computer (maybe I can use it some day).

Comment: Usually OP's cannot easily delete their own questions, when there are answers. Moderators can delete questions instantly, or other members with enough rep can vote for deletion (AFAIR it need's 4 or 5 deletion votes until the question is deleted). _"so I would like to have the chance to access my answer after the question is deleted"_ You can, as soon you have 10k rep.

Comment: If you get 10k you can see deleted questions and answers.

Comment: Indeed. And they have to take in consideration the answers when deleting questions. I suggest to edit those closed questions to bring them up to standard.

Comment: @PatrickHofman The OP can't see deleted questions, neither would be able to edit them. We're talking about _deleted_ questions, not _[on hold]_ (_closed_).

Comment: I was referring to closed, not deleted questions. You can edit them before they get deleted. This even might get them reopened. Problem fixed.

Comment: you do not get notified if a question, that you answerd, is getting deleted. maybe it is possible to access the own deleted answers bevor 10k reputation.

Comment: You could use SEDE to make a backup of your own answers every once in a while.

Comment: I could also safe the answer, direct after answering, to a private database or a text file. But I thought posting it on stack overflow saves me that step.

Comment: SO is not a replacement for your personal database. Content *can* get deleted. Hence it is best to keep your answers you want to keep in some form of personal storage.

Comment: @PatrickHofman IMO [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/145673) should be a site feature. Expecting everyone to keep personal backups of answers contributed in good faith sucks. Your suggestion of using SEDE isn't reliable as that doesn't show deleted content. Technically it would be easy to implement as the content is there anyway and I believe mods see it linked from the profile. I think the rationale is just that keeping deletion opaque avoids complaints about deleted content.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for sharing the link and the bounty on the question. Looks like this feature will not be implemented very soon :(

Comment: @Scimonster You can only get to them if you have a link to them. Deleted answers won't show up in your profile, or in searches. Well, there's a link for "deleted recent answers" in the profile, but as the name suggests, that only keeps recent answers accessible.

Comment: @AbcAeffchen Right, you do not get notified directly if your answer is deleted along with a question. You do see it in your reputation updates if it had upvotes.

Comment: @RetoKoradi This only works if the answer had upvotes what is not always the case for unpopular questions. It is also too late, since I have the link to the deleted answers but not enough reputation to see it.

Comment: If a question is too theoretical for SO and not getting any love and less than 60 days old, it may find a better home on [cs.se]. Moderators can migrate questions that are less than 60 days old.

Answer (score 2):

Normally if you tick the "show removed posts" at the bottom of the reputation tab on your profile page you'll be able to see recently deleted answers there.

However, if the OP of the question deleted it then it means that your's was the only answer and it hadn't been upvoted so it won't appear in this list as there were no reputation changes.

Comment: You can also see recent deleted answers at the bottom of the answers tab on your profile. (The answer has to be recent, not just the deletion.) But that doesn't help much because you can't browse it unless you have 10k rep.